# Cant understand why this url mapping is working?

Tags: python, django, url, url-mapping

I am currently going through various Django tutorials in order to understand how url mapping is working . I came across an example which is something like this

this is in my urls.py

```
url(r'admin_page_edit$',"adminApp.views.showClientDetails",name="admin_page_edit"),
```

this is in my html page that is currently being displayed to the user

```
<a href="{% url "admin_page_edit" %}?uname=SomeVal&par2=value" >
```

Now the URL the browser shows when the above href link is clicked. No problem there

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin_page_edit?uname=SomeVal&par2=value
```

And the above URL  lands in the corresponding view

```
adminApp.views.showClientDetails
```

Now here is the proble, this seems to all work but I am confused as to why this is working ? since the url of the browser is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin_page_edit?uname=SomeVal&par2=value
```

which does not match the regex string in the url

```
admin_page_edit$
```

(The above regex means if the string ends with `admin_page_edit`) but the url string does not end with  `admin_page_edit` instead it is

```
  http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin_page_edit?uname=SomeVal&par2=value
```

thus ending with `par2=value`

My question is why is this hitting the corresponding definition in the view when the url regex is not matching ?

Comment: The ? usually means what follows will be values. The page ends before the ? and what follows is the values that will be sent to the POST method for that page

Comment: The mapping maps against the path of the URL, which in your case is `/admin_page_edit`, which matches. The `?...` part of a URL is the [query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) (**not** POST data btw).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query strings (parts following `?`) are not processed by the Django url parser. Why? Because they don't have to be processed. You can just about append any query string to any url:

Like: https://www.facebook.com/?request=pleasedonotwork which works all the same. Unless redirects (*or some logging*) are done based on queries sent in urls, you can consider the query part of urls as *passive*.

These query strings can be accessed in your Django views via the `request.GET` `QueryDict`